# Spring rest docs generated content not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restdocs

I'm using Spring REST Docs to generate documentation for our API.
I've added everything to build.gradle from tutorial here http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/

```
ext {
    snippetsDir = file('build/generated-snippets')
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

asciidoctor {
    attributes 'snippets': snippetsDir
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    outputDir "build/asciidoc"
    dependsOn test
    sourceDir 'src/main/asciidoc'
}

jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/docs'
    }
}
```

After I do `gradle build` I can see that in `build/asciidoc` directory files are generated and also in `build/generated-snippets`.

But when I run from IDEA gradle task `bootRun` and trying to access localhost:8080/docs/index.html I'm getting not found 404. Just for test I've tried to put some `index.html` file under `resources/static` directory and then do `bootRun` and I can access `localhost:8080/index.html` file after that.

If I open my .jar file I can see static files under directory `BOOT-INF/classes/static/docs` so they are packed into jar.

Maybe somebody had the same issue?

Comment: With the Gradle configuration you've shown, `bootRun` won't have run your tests or generated the HTML from your Asciidoctor.

Comment: Is it possible to generate it with bootRun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that you need to do so that the documentation is served when using `bootRun`. The first is to copy the generated documentation into a location that's on the classpath used by `bootRun`:

```
task copyRestDocs(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from "${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5"
    into "${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/static/docs"
}
```

Note that this new task depends on the `asciidoctor` task. This ensures that the documentation has been generated before it's copied.

Secondly, the `bootRun` task must depend on the new `copyRestDocs` task:

```
bootRun {
    dependsOn copyRestDocs
}
```

Comment: +1 On the downside if test cases take long time to finish, `bootRun` will take time to initialise as well.